# wkhtmltopdf page break creates white space in table

Tags: php, symfony, pdf, wkhtmltopdf, knp-snappy

I have implemented knpsnappy bundle that generates pdf using wkhtmtltopdf library.

I have used `page-break-inside: avoid !important;` css in tr it creates page break is working fine. But it created white unnecessary space in table inside of `tr`. You can see in image.
[image]

I have checked html generated for this pdf and it looks good in html view.

So it would be good if there is any solution for this.

Comment: Hi, have you got a solution ?

Comment: Hi, I didn't get any proper solution. But I have tried to manage somehow with css page-break-inside: avoid something like this. I don't remember exactly.